# Why does try_files not force an immediate 404 response?

Tags: linux, nginx

nginx location set up by a variable if, but `try_files` did not perform the last condition, directly return to 404.
my nginx config is as follows:

```
location ~ /linux/(.*).html {
    if ($uri ~* ^(/linux/("shell-"|about))) {
        set $xheader ""; 
    }   
    try_files /linux/$xheader$1.html /linux/$xheader/$1.html @upst;
}
```

But nignx log output here is not what i expected:

```
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http script var: "/linux/about.html"
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http script regex: "^(/linux/("shell-"|about))"
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [notice] 14701#14701: *4 "^(/linux/("shell-"|about))" matches "/linux/about.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: upst.com, request: "GET /linux/about.html HTTP/1.1", host: "upst.com"
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http script if
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http script value: ""
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http script set $xheader
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http filename: "/var/www/cache_html/upst/linux/about.html"
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 add cleanup: 000055BD85012D38
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 cached open file: /var/www/cache_html/upst/linux/about.html, fd:-1, c:0, e:2, u:8
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [error] 14701#14701: *4 open() "/var/www/cache_html/upst/linux/about.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: upst.com, request: "GET /linux/about.html HTTP/1.1", host: "upst.com"
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http finalize request: 404, "/linux/about.html?" a:1, c:1
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 http special response: 404, "/linux/about.html?"
2017/09/24 12:31:52 [debug] 14701#14701: *4 internal redirect: "/404.html?"
```

my question is `@upst` why not work?
thanks.

Comment: Post complete config and show @upst also

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 0):

To force an immediate 404 you would write:

```
try_files /linux/$xheader$1.html /linux/$xheader/$1.html =404;
```

as described in the documentation: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files.

What you are doing is telling NGiNX to fall back to a location named `@upst`, which you did not include in your question, so I can't really tell you anything about the effects from that location.

The configuration you've written does exactly what it should, even the `if` does, though you really should read https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/.